# error in uploading and saving image in database

Tags: asp.net

i am facing problem with saving and uploading image.
this is my code:

**asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server"**

```
    ContentTemplate

div style="position: absolute; top: 53px; left: -22px;
```

**input id="picupload" type="file" runat="server" onchange="File_OnChange(this)" style="visibility:
 hidden;"**

div

**asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Button"**

this is my javascript on which i am calling my btnupload event:

function File_OnChange(sender) {

```
         document.getElementById('<%=btnUpload.ClientID%>').click();
```

}

**ContentTemplate**

```
    **Triggers**

        **asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnsave"** 

    **/Triggers>**

**/asp:UpdatePanel**
```

this whole code is under update panel.i am having one save button and i want this data to be posted on server on btnsave button event.

but problem is when i am selecting image my page load event fires again and error is coming on this line:

**string strName = picupload.PostedFile.FileName;**

error is :Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

can anyone tell me why my page load event is firing second time??
plz plz plz plz

Comment: why you are using html control for file upload instead of use asp.net control <asp:FileUpload ID="flupld" runat="server" />

Comment: bt my question is why page load event is fired for second time?